# SQL Error on Heroku with Rails after deployment

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Rails App works perfect local and on my own linux root (with sqlite to test it)

After uploading it to heroku, i have a small problem.

Half of my requests does not work anymore.

All Requests with a ".where()" condition are broken.

Here is a small code snippet from my controller:

```
def GameModeB
  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
  @highscore = Highscore.where("gamemode = \"b\"").order("points DESC").limit(100)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @highscore }
    format.json  { render :json =>  @highscore}
  end
end
```

This is my errorlog from heroku log

```
2011-12-07T12:21:08+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...highscores".* FROM "highscores" WHERE (gamemode = "b") ORDER...
2011-12-07T12:21:08+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2011-12-07T12:21:08+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "highscores".* FROM "highscores" WHERE (gamemode = "b") ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 100): 2
```

The Problem is **where("gamemode = *\"b\""***)

So what is the correct statement and why does it not work on heroku this was ? thx

Comment: Heroku uses Postgres - you should try to have the same environment in development as in production. For your specific question, a solution would be to write the query like this: `@highscore = Highscore.where(:gamemode => "b").order("points DESC").limit(100)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres allows only single quotes for string literals. See this [wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL) about migrating from mySQL to Postgres. Holds good for sqlite as well.

Comment: This has solved the problem. Thank you.
@eugen Your code sample looks more "clean" than mine. Will refactor the statements